# How to hide selection checkbox in grid?

Tags: java, smartgwt

I have a `TreeGrid` with selection appearence set to checkbox.

```
TreeGrid resultGrid = new TreeGrid();
resultGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

I want some records to be drawn without these checkboxes(in case record is disabled).
I found property ***showDisabledSelectionCheckbox***, which description says:

> Should tree nodes show a disabled checkbox instead of a blank space  when selectionAppearance:"checkbox"  is set on the treegrid, and a node ***can't be selected***?

How I can make the node "unselectable" except setting :

> node.setEnabled(false);

And how this property(showDisabledSelectionCheckbox) works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TreeGrid` has selection property that can be set via

```
resultGrid.setSelectionProperty(propertyName);
```

So setting this property on `TreeNodes` will define if nodes could be selected.
By default one can just use **"canSelect"** property.

So this line of code will disable selection of the particular node.

```
treeNode.setAttribute("canSelect", false);
```

And if selection appearance is set to `SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX`, checkboxes **won't be drawn** near nodes which couldn't be selected.
This is the only way I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I would start [here](http://forums.smartclient.com/showpost.php?p=77987&postcount=13).  It looks like you can override [canEditCell()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#canEditCell%28int,%20int%29) on the ListGrid itself to keep someone from interacting with the checkbox.  I haven't been able to find a method to hide the checkbox completely, however.

Perhaps setting the showDisabledSelectionCheckbox property to false in conjunction with overriding canEditCell() will get you where you're looking to go.